# How do I fill text in android from an object?

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to populate textview with information from objects. I am new to android development and I do not know how to approach this. Hard Coding this in the xml will not work because eventually I would like to open up the same activity but with different information.

I do not know if this is enough information but thank you for responding and if code is needed I would be more than willing to upload code or screen shots.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
textview.setText(user.getName());
```

Refer this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)